# Override AuthorizationEndpoint with custom implementation

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-web

I'd like to override spring's default `AuthorizationEndpoint` and provide my own on `/oauth/authorize`. I wrote my own controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("oauth/authorize")
public class AuthorizationController {

    @RequestMapping
    public void authorize(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
     // todo   
    }

}
```

However it is not mapped as `AuthorizationEndpoint` maps to `/oauth/authorize` by default. How can I remove the standard implementation?

**Bonus**

The reason  I want to provide my own implementation is because my rest api is stateless and does not provide sessions and/or web interface, standalone angular app does that for me and authorizes using passwrd grant to server. So what I want to do is redirect the user to my angular app's approoval page and implement a custom `user_oauth_approval` **approveOrDeny** endpoint which my client calls. I'm not sure if  I can set that up with spring, and even if I could, custom implementation would probably be less hassle. I'd love to hear some insights

Comment: Don't do it, you get a big security problem. However, if you use password grant, the authorization endpoint is not used at all. Hence, there is no need to override the authorization endpoint.

Comment: Did you find any solution for it? I too have the same scenario. Would be great if you can share it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inject your customAuthenticationManager in your new controller.

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@RequestMapping(value = "${jwt.route.authentication.path}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        Authentication customAuthentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(customAuthentication.getToken(), customAuthentication.isActive()));

    }
```

Then overwrite default Spring AuthenticationManager + AuthenticationProvider

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;

@Component("customAuthenticationProvider")
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
```